# ctrl-] does not work for tags consist of special character ( operators in haskell )

Tags: tags

I'm using [codex](https://github.com/aloiscochard/codex) for generating tags file but vim does not follow
tags such as

`$ <$> . <*>`

with `ctrl-]` it only works if I manually call tag

`:tag $`

Is it a bug? or there is something that I don't know

thanks

Comment: Does it work if you highlight the text in visual mode first?

Comment: yes it does, that's weird. thanks it makes it easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ctrl-]` uses the `word` under the cursor, (as opposed to a `WORD`) which means that any punctuation is excluded.

From `:h word`:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>   tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>   is also considered to be a word.

So your options are:

1. Select it with visual mode first to tell it explicitly what you want to search for, or
2. Change the mapping to use a `WORD` (which is any white space separated characters).

You can do so with the following mapping in your `vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <silent><C-]> :exe "tag ".expand('<cWORD>')<CR>
```

- `nnoremap`: create a non-recursive, normal mode mapping
- `<silent><C-]>`: map CTRL + ] and do it without echoing anything
- `:exe`: execute the following string as a command
- `"tag "`: use the tag command
- `.expand('<cWORD>')`: append the `WORD` under the cursor to the tag command
- `<CR>`: a carriage return. Simply executes the command.

Please note that doing this will not allow you to use tags in the vim help files as they surround their tags with `||`!

See `:h word`, `:h WORD` for more info.

Comment: Nice. I was curious how to solve that question. Additionally, this mapping can be put in `~/.vim/ftplugin/<extension>.vim` - which will make it only available in certain file type only - so help will be still working (or use autocommand for `FileType`)